# Acer Aspire V3-772G fan direction

Tags: laptop, fan, acer-aspire, overheating

I'm not a hardware person. If the computer runs, I'm happy. If it randomly shuts down, I'm not. I recently bought a second hand Acer Aspire V3-772G and noticed that it gets very hot very fast, even though there is no dust around the fan.

I only now noticed something: my laptop is blowing air OUT of the bottom of the laptop and is sucking it IN at the grill on the side. This does not seem right to me, is this the cause of my overheating? If so, how can I change the direction that the fan is spinning in?

Comment: simplest would be turn the fan over

Comment: @Tetsujin So I am correct when I think that the fan should blow air *out* of the side and *in* from the bottom?

Comment: It might be best to take a picture :)

Comment: standard is in the bottom, out the top, for most form-factors. Some fans will mount both ways, some won't. That might help you decide, too.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the airflow is in the wrong direction. In any case, it would be extremely difficult to fit most fans upside-down so it's very unlikely that that could have happened.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the airflow is in the wrong direction because I can feel it and bits of paper get blown in the direction I suspect.